# Privilege that I have not yet earned is shown in Achievements

Tags: support, privileges, achievements-dialog

[image]

I didn't earn the "edit community wiki" privilege on Stack Overflow, but it shows in the recent achievements list.

Comment: See [your reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8101287/ankit-agrawal?tab=reputation): it says “today: 0”, which means that there were some changes that added up to 0. Most likely someone accepted one of your answers (+15) then immediately unaccepted it (−15), causing your rep to reach 100 for a short amount of time. Also, this is a privilege, not a badge.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SO: [Getting award for achieving the down vote privilege without any reputation changes inside account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280575/4642212).

Comment: but then it would have shown about the (+15) and (-15) in the inbox, or not? @SebastianSimon

Comment: aha got you, thanks @SebastianSimon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the same case as @SebastianSimon found on Meta Stack Overflow. Apparently, this question hasn't been asked on Meta Stack Exchange yet (or my duplicate finding skills aren't working before the first coffee of the day).

Your [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8101287/ankit-agrawal?tab=reputation) shows no net changes for the day:

[image]

Following the template from [@Oded's answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280580/4751173):

> Why bother with it if there were no rep changes?
>
> Well, that's not true - there *were* rep changes, but the sum total (net) of them was zero.
>
> That means there were some votes happening that got reversed (most likely an accept, taking you over 100, followed by an un-accept).
>
> Now, you were briefly at 100, so you got the privilege - and a notification was sent and received.
>
> We don't retract notifications, so you saw that, even though that by the time you got it, you lost the privilege :/

Comment: Yeah, most likely accept that was undone shortly afterwards.

Comment: But I think deleted comments are pulled from notifications. That’s strange.

Comment: That happens fairly often, so I guess the developers made the effort to support that case (which makes "We don't retract notifications" false, though e.g. iOS push notifications can't be retracted). What the OP describes happens only rarely and apparently isn't worth the effort to fix.